# Is .find() faster than basic descendant selecting method?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

Slide 30 in [Paul Irish's blog](http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/) mentioned:

`$('#container').find('div.robotarm')` is faster than `$('#container div.robotarm')`

Is this true?

Comment: I'd say opinions count for nothing. Create some benchmarks and run them multiple times (preferably on different browsers) and check the results. That's the only way to get a definitive answer, IMO.

Comment: https://forrst.com/posts/I_ran_a_little_speed_test_on_jQuery_selectors_Y-3mQ This might help.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe in an earlier version of jQuery that was the case. However, the expression

```
$('#container div.robotarm')
```

is normalized through jQuery into

```
$('#container').find('div.robotarm')
```

So the only reason why `$('#container div.robotarm')` should be slower is because of function call overhead. But, that would really be a trivial difference.

If that call wasn't normalized, `sizzle` (Resigs css selector engine) would be used to lookup that element (right to left). That of course would be much slower.

Comment: Can anyone cite some documentation to back this up? Couldn't find anything on a quick google search.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for opinion, it doesn't matter.

You can always come up with a case where one runs faster than the other in some browser under a certain configuration of the DOM. No need to split hairs.

Answer (score 1):

This is only correct when searching by ID.

But when we search by tag name it returns different results in modern browsers where `$('div').find('p')` is slower than `$('div p')` because the latter uses `querySelector()`.