# $('#id tag') vs. $('#id').find('tag') - which is preferable?

Tags: jquery, performance

I want to know which option is better, particularly in terms of their speed:

```
$('#id tag')...
```

or

```
$('#id').find('tag')...
```

Also, would the same answer apply if you change `id` and/or `tag` to, say, a `class` or something like `input:checked`?

For example, which is better: `$('#id input:checked')...` or `$('#id').find('input:checked');`?

Comment: try running a test case in http://jsperf.com

Comment: Yeah, I've been running quite a few. Trouble is, I really want to know the theoretical answer and not just get results that may apply to my particular test conditions.

Comment: there's the third options as well: `$("tag", "#id");` When you'll do performance test, make sure you try all three.

Comment: @ravi jsperf is ok , buf theres a different results between browsers

Comment: The answer really depends on what browser you are talking about. For example, there will be a big difference between a browser that supports `querySelectorAll` and one that doesn't.

Comment: Any question that can be phrased as which is better, X or Y?  Should be tested and, if those results show something odd, or you don't understand the results, then ask about them. This question could have been answered yourself, quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help and encouragement, @DavidThomas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can base your decision on 3 things:

**Readability**

This is not much of a difference with your two given selectors. For my part, I prefer the `$('#id').find('inner')` syntax because it describes more accurately what it is actually doing.

**Reusability**

If you have other parts of your code use the same id selector (or something in its context), you can cache the selector and reuse it. I myself find it harder to refactor code that has been written like this `$('#id inner')`, because you have to decode the css selector first before you can move on and find possible improvements.

Imagine these two cases with not much complexity

```
$('#hello .class_name tag').doThis();
$('#hello .other_name input').doThat();
```

And the other case

```
$('#hello').find('.class_name tag').doThis();
$('#hello').find('.other_name input').doThat();
```

I think the second example screams at you «Cache the id selector», and the first does not.

**Speed**

Performance is always a good point, and in this case, the id selector with the `find` does the better job in most browsers, because it establishes the context first and can apply the descending selector to a smaller subset of elements.

[Here's a good performance test, if you want to know more about context-vs subset selectors performance in jQuery](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-selector). Subsets of ids *generally* rule. Of course you can get different results, but in most cases, they do.

So, 3 to 0 for subset selectors from my point of view.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the test case HTML where I look for all `span` elements under `#i` element:

```
<div id="i">
  <span>testL1_1</span>
  <span>testL1_2</span>
  <div>
    <span>testL2_1</span>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>testL3_1</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>testL5_1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Testing these three jQuery selectors:

```
$("#i span");         // much slower
$("#i").find("span"); // FASTEST
$("span", "#i");      // second fastest
```

http://jsperf.com/jquery-sub-element-selection

I've run it on Google Chrome and Firefox and it seems that `.find()` is the fastest closely followed by the third case and much slower first one.

[image: jQuery selector performance]

Answer (score 2):

Performance measure here: `:)`**==>** http://jsperf.com/find-vs-descendant-selector

Seems like `descendant` way is lil faster but perform poorly in opera,

anyhoo in my opinion it doesn't matter `:)`

Hope this answers your question and see here [Is .find() faster than basic descendant selecting method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422230/is-find-faster-than-basic-descendant-selecting-method)

Comment: Thanks for this. It was actually a half-recollection of Paul Irish's "lecture" that prompted the question; I seem to recall that he said the jQuery engine processes them differently. I was hoping for a fuller explanation :)

Comment: Say hi to Paul when you see him next `:P` @Nick Glad it is clear I would recommend that you should performance test it of your own, you know it will get more interesting if you look for memory leaks `:P` yes I said the ML word `:)` bruv!

Comment: I confess I don't know how to look for memory leaks :(  But I'll say hi to Paul...

Comment: @Nick read this bruv - http://blog.linkibol.com/2010/05/07/did-you-know-that-jquery-leaks-memory-like-a-fountain/ **please note* this is old blog and on "our" fav browser I.E. `:)`

Comment: But your selector doesn't look for *ID and tag*, but rather **ID and tag with CSS class** and that's not the same.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik hmm I reckon O well deserve dv then `:)` please feel free to dv but thanks for that bruv!

Comment: Oh it+s not as invalid to deserve a downvote. I gave -1 to the *speculative* answer by @Utkanos that subsequently deleted their answer because it was based on speculation and no real data.

Comment: Hoya, hope life is good! @RobertKoritnik Thanks! for that, `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that the first one `$("#id tag")` is **much** slower than the second (`$("#id").find("tag")`) on modern browsers; [test here](http://jsperf.com/descendant-selector-vs-find), see screenshot below. IE7 (which lacks `querySelectorAll`) runs them at roughly the same speed.

But two observations:

1. It's extremely unlikely to actually matter. If you aren't debugging an actual, known performance problem, don't worry about it.
2. Synthetic benchmarks are always suspect. If you're fighting an actual, known performance problem, profile *that* (your actual selector and your actual markup).

[image: Results screenshot]

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought they both deferred to the same functionality behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Descendant performs better. check for this link [Jsperf](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-hierarchy-slectors) .

1. if you have too many nested element. then go for find. it's really a small amount of difference.
2. it's just your convienent way of coding. i prefer if too many nested items are there, then i will go for find,

Comment: The problem with your test is that you're not looking for ID only and also it may be that majority of time is spent manipulating CSS. Minor difference reflects that. Check my performance results where those are eliminated and show a much different results. Difference in order of 3-times.

Answer (score 1):

as ive said - its different in browsers.

## chrome :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SijQY.jpg
[image]

## ie

https://i.stack.imgur.com/axhGw.jpg
[image]