# whats the better way to retrieve an element inside another?

Tags: jquery, performance

What the better way to select an element inside another:

1. `var elem = $('#container').find('ul');`
2. `var elem = $('#container ul');`
3. `var elem = $('ul', '#container');`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, they all work and the speed difference is so small you wouldn't even notice it on thousands of elements.

Comment: That said, the second one is usually what you want, unless there's a reason to use `find()`, and the third is just a shortcut for the first.

Comment: Because #1 and #3 are functionally equivalent, you can find your answer over at [jQuery: $('#id tag') vs. $('#id').find('tag') - which is preferable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502563/jquery-id-tag-vs-id-findtag-which-is-preferable)

Comment: there is one more way....use parent.children(childElement) method to select an element inside another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here's](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors03)** a test with Chrome 33, Firefox 14 and IE 11

Code use:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer use to be `The shorter the better`. However, when benchmarking this, using jQuery here it doesn't make any significative difference. Anyways, I find this pretty and more concise:

```
var elem = $('#container ul');
```