# jQuery efficiency

Tags: jquery, html

I have a query like this:

```
$('#tabContainer li');
```

And JetBrains WebStorm IDE highlights it as an inefficient query. It suggests me to use this instead:

```
$('#tabContainer').find('li')
```

How can it be explained? Are there docs explaining such cases?

Comment: I would use the first one as well. Don't worry.

Comment: This question should help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422230/1370034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/), there is a part of specificity (Fourth point).

If you have `$('#tabContainer li')`, all `li` you have in the document wil be queried. Then each of those `li` would be checked to see if they have a parent `#tabContainer`.

To get it quicker, `$('#tabContainer').find('li')` can be used. The li would be searched in the #tabContainer, which is unique in the document.

But apparently, if you are selecting using an ID, there should not be much improvement in performance (from the answer on this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028555/1370034) which also talks about specificity).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will translate the former expression into the latter. Therefore the only difference is some calling overhead within jQuery. It's negligible in my opinion.

But: `$('#tabContainer').find('li')` improves readability (at least for people who are not very familiar with the selector syntax) and I'd consider that a good reason to use it..

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reasoning for the optimization is speed. Find can be extremely fast but it would not hurt to benchmark your particular use case. For instance, here is a test that uses a few possible variations similar to what you are trying to do.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-sel/9

In this case find is extremely fast. Now, if you are only running that selection one time; it really does not matter which way you do it as long as it is easy to read/understand its intent.